# Linux Fedora: How to open a file with a random application

Tags: fedora, file-opening

I downloaded a cross-assembler that as far I can tell, i am supposed to open a .txt file with it and the assembler will create an a.out file somewhere. But Fedora only lets me open .txt files with programs in its apps list. How do I put a program in the apps list or how do I simply open a file with an application outside of Fedora's app list? Thanks so much.

Comment: Which file manager are you using?

Comment: I use the one that comes with Fedora 22...

Answer (score 1):

On my fedora 22 with dolphin I right click on the file icon which opens
a dialog with a list of programs to choose from.  If I don't want to use 
any of those listed I choose 'Other...' which open another dialog where I
can browse the whole system to the file I want to use

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a desktop-file in `~/.local/share/applications` of that application

For example for a *.desktop file:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/txtEditor %u
Name=MyPrivateTXTEditor
```

Source:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2242613-fedora-30-setting-file-association-with-non-standard-application